# Exclude a specific element from selection through XPath in mule-esb transformation

Tags: xpath, mule

I have a web service response in the below mentioned format. I use xpath to lookup the root element <**returnObjs**> within mule for transformational purposes. Is there a way to lookup the root element <**returnObjs**> in such a way that <**newElement**> element never gets picked up in the xpath lookup ? 
Please note that <**returnObjs**> is a list of <**returnObj**> type and so there could be multiple <**returnObj**> objects that may/may not have <**newElement**> element in it.

```
<ns2:root>    
 <returnObjs>
 <!-- 1 or more repititions -->
 <returnObj>
    <EL1>A</EL1>
    <EL2>B</EL2>
    <Top>
       <TopEl1>data1</TopEl1>
       <TopEl2>data2</TopEl2>
       <TopEl3>data3</TopEl3> 
       <newElement>new value</newElement>
       <Nested>
          <Nested1el1>val1</Nested1el1>
          <Nested1el2 />
          <Nestedel3>val2</Nestedel3>
          <Nestedel4>val3</Nestedel4>
       </Nested>
    </Top>
 </returnObj>
 <returnObjs>
</ns2:root>
```

Note : I am evaluating /root/*[not(newElement)] but so far it has not worked for me.

Comment: You mention newElement attribute but I only see newElement as an element, not an attribute

Answer (score 1):

No. XPath is a tool for *selecting* nodes from an XML tree - it can either select a particular `returnObj` or not select it, but it can't modify the element's content.

You would need a transformation tool such as XSLT in order to build a new XML document based on the incoming one, with the desired elements removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want select all elements but newElement use xpath

```
/*[name() != "newElement"]
```